# I'll eat as much as I can put in this little bowl

Tags: spoken-english

I know the sentence in the title sounds kind of weird but it was from a show in my native language. So here a guy's on a diet. So he picks up a small bowl and says that:

> I'm going to eat **as much as** I can put in this little bowl.

I couldn't think of a natural way to express this idea. Actually the guy will eat only the amount of food he can put in the bowl. So how can it be expressed naturally?

Comment: Your sentence is fine, although it might be better to say "I'm going to eat **only as much as** I can put in this little bowl," where the **only** emphasizes that it's a limited amount.

Answer (score 1):

> Your sentence is fine, although it might be better to say "I'm going to eat only as much as I can put in this little bowl," where the only emphasizes that it's a limited amount.

As Stated above by Canada Yankee, **Only** Emphasizes the Limited amount, adding it as an Adjective to the sentence WILL add that form of "Natural Wording" That you want.

Comment: Although I think it sounds more natural to say *I'm **only** going to eat as much as I can put in this little bowl*